# Can anyone HELP provide codes to import 'CHARTEVENTS' and 'NOTEEVENTS' in sas or R?

Tags: mimic-iii, programming

I tried R and SAS to import these two datasets, but the programming runs forever. I could not open in excel either. Can anyone provide codes to import these two table: 'CHARTEVENTS' and 'NOTEEVENTS' ?

Answer (score 2):

**For R:**

As you probably know, `CHARTEVENTS` and `NOTEEVENTS` are on the large size for datasets, and will require special handling to import into `R`, unless you have a lot of RAM.  It is likely preferable to import them into an RDBM like postgres or even sqlite and do data manipulation there.  There are even a couple good interfaces, like `dplyr` and `data.table` that work well within R and use pg or sqlite effectively.

From the command prompt:

```
> sqlite3 mimic
```

Then within sqlite3:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import "CHARTEVENTS.csv" chartevents
```

Open up R:

```
library(dplyr);
d <- src_sqlite( "mimic") #opens the mimic database you created
charte <- tbl(d,"chartevents") #uses the "chartevents" table we created
```

You can then for instance run any of the `dplyr` operations on the charte object.  For example, get the number of chartevents rows for each ICUSTAY_ID in chart events for subject id #23:

```
charte %>% filter(SUBJECT_ID==23) %>% collect() %>% group_by(ICUSTAY_ID) %>% summarise(n=n())
```

This is likely slow, but can be improved with some indexing.

---

With all this said, you can likely use some special function to import the data into R using the `ff` package from CRAN:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html

It stores most of the data on disk, so it's not going to be very fast for many things.

To import `CHARTEVENTS`, I believe you could use:

```
library(ff)

charte <- read.csv.ffdf(file="CHARTEVENTS.csv", header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE, first.rows=10000, next.rows=500000, colClasses=NA)
```

You may have to play around with the `colClasses` to make it work.

---

**For SAS**:

You need to create a SAS library with enough disk space to store the csv files and the the SAS formatted `sas7bdat` file.  For chartevents this can be significant and in my experience the `sas7bdat` file is a little bit larger than the uncompressed CSV.

I used he University Edition of SAS, and had to create a new library on the shared folder, as the SAS VM doesn't have enough space within the VM environment by default.  My library is called `TMP` and you will have to replace xxxxxx with the place you put the data:

```
%web_drop_table(TMP.IMPORT);


FILENAME REFFILE '/folders/myshortcuts/xxxxxx/CHARTEVENTS.csv';

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=REFFILE
    DBMS=CSV
    OUT=TMP.IMPORT;
    GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;

PROC CONTENTS DATA=TMP.IMPORT; RUN;


%web_open_table(TMP.IMPORT);
```

---

The good news: my VM has only 1GB of ram, and it worked.  The bad news: it took almost an hour to import.